# Frameset not showing when text is added outside it

Tags: html, frame, frameset

In the HTML code below, the frameset doesn't appear, but only the text "abc" appears. However, if the text "abc" is removed from the code, the frameset appears. I don't understand why that happens. Shouldn't the frameset appear below the text "abc"?

```
<html>
<head>

abc

<frameset border=0 cols="170,*">
<frame marginwidth=10 src="navigation.html" name="left" scrolling=auto>
</frameset>

</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is invalid.

You can have either a `<body>` or `<frameset>`, not both. Any non-metadata text must appear in the `<body>` or `<noframes>` element.

So no, the frameset shouldn't appear below the `abc`. The `abc` tells the browser that this is a regular HTML document with regular content and not a frameset document.